# how to insert between multiple rows a button

Tags: html, jquery

so i wanna insert 2 buttons after every first td where the img is. i wanna do this with a script. so i get the table from a server and the site should automatically add the buttons with a script

```
<html>
<body>
<tr style="background:#EEE;line-height:1.4em">
                    <td width="50%">
                        <div class="extra_info" style="padding: 2px 0 0;">
                            <img class="detach_prop_or_tag" title="entfernen"
                                name="prop_id=656|page_id=10280|confirm_text=: 1108"
                                src="/theme/frontend/prinvision/style/prinvision/image/layout/cancel_button.png">
                            Adressat (Angebot)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" id="propId_656_profilePageId_10280" class="editable_prop">
                        <span class="extra_info" title="Adressat (Angebot): example6">
                            <a href="#" title="Adressat (Angebot): exampletext5">exampletext4</a></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background:#FFF;line-height:1.4em">
                    <td width="50%">
                        <div class="extra_info" style="padding: 2px 0 0;">
                            <img class="detach_prop_or_tag" title="entfernen"
                                name="prop_id=838|page_id=10280|confirm_text=: 1108"
                                src="/theme/frontend/prinvision/style/prinvision/image/layout/cancel_button.png">
                            Absender (Angebot)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" id="propId_838_profilePageId_10280" class="editable_prop">
                        <span class="extra_info" title="Absender (Angebot): exampletext3">
                            <a href="#" title="Absender (Angebot): exampletext">exampletext2</a></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<\body>
<\html>
```

i have tryd multiple scripts but i cant figure out the right one.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - you can't insert buttons in between table cells

Comment: where is you `javascript`

Comment: You've asked how to insert between two rows (`tr`)and after first `td` (column) - which is it?  And how do you want to do this, with javascript/jquery? (as tagged [tag:javascript] but an edit looks like it's incorrectly removing that)

Comment: Notice your example code is missing a `table` tag. If this is your real code this may lead to unexpected display of the content, depending where you use it.

Comment: sorry i have forgotten to say that i wanna do this with jquery

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    table,td,tr,div{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/USDnotesNew.png" height="20px" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgdiv"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>hello1</td>
      <td>hello1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/USDnotesNew.png" height="20px" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgdiv"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>hello2</td>
      <td>hello2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/USDnotesNew.png" height="20px" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>
         <div class="imgdiv"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>hello3</td>
      <td>hello3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// this way you can select every image and add button with it 

// i hope your issue is slove if not can explian more like
add button in next td or after image

var img= $('.imgdiv');

$.each(img, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
  console.log(indexInArray, valueOfElement);
  $(this).parent().find('.imgdiv').html(`<button>button-${indexInArray}</button><button>btn-${indexInArray}</button>`)
  
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you need to add the buttons - in the second td, or after the row? Depending on your answer, you can the below approach:

Either add buttons in a new td after every image td

```
<td>
  <button onclick="performAction">Action</button>
</td>
```

Or, add a new row below your image tr, and insert a full-width td containing the buttons.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">
    <button onclick="performAction">Action</button>
 </td>
</tr>
```